# Uploading BIG file using Http-Client

Tags: java, file-upload, httpclient

I am trying to upload a file on server using `HTTP Client`.it is successfully doing its task.but when i am trying to upload a Zip file of size 1.5 GB then it is throwing an

> exception: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or
>   multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null

please help,how can i resolve this*

Comment: Try this http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Comment: i am using the same...

Comment: If you are using a "FileItem" it will store in memory until it finish uploading. So use "DiskFileItem" and set the buffer to zero. (http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set a proper content type in http header. Set content type as "application/zip".